# Publish to Azure App Service crashes after upgrade to asp.net core rc2

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, crash, publish

When I try to publish a Asp.net core RC2 application to Azure app service, Visual Studio will crash when I press the last Publish -button in the wizard. On the previous page I can press Preview and it will list all changes. Sometimes it seems to crash even before I press Publish.

When I debug the crash with another instance of Visual Studio I get this information:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: DialogResult can be set only after Window is
>   created and shown as dialog.

or

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

I tried running VS in safe mode but when I go to the Publish wizard is says

> The 'CommonAzureToolsPackage' package did not load correctly

and in ActivityLog.xml I see

> 823
>       2016/06/02 07:27:13.770
>       Error
>       VisualStudio
>       SetSite failed for package [CommonAzureToolsPackage][Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.]:{   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.Authentication.KeychainUtil.<<SetAccountManager>b__0>d__1.MoveNext()
> ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.Authentication.KeychainUtil.<GetVSAccountProviderAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
> ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.KeychainEndpointProvider.<GetInstanceAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
> ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.EndpointProviderFactory.<CreateEndpointProviderList>d__3.MoveNext()
> ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.EndpointProviderFactory.<GetEndpointProviderAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
> ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.EndpointProviderFactory.GetEndpointProvider()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.CommonAzureToolsPackage.<.ctor>b__1()
>
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.CommonAzureToolsPackage.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__2()&#x000D;&#x000A;
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.CommonAzureToolsPackage.<RegisterServices>b__61(IServiceContainer
>   c, Type t)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.IServiceProviderExtensions.GetService[InterfaceType,ServiceType](IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.ServerExplorer.AzureNodeStateManager.Initialize(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.CommonAzureToolsPackage.InitializeAzureNodeStateManager()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.CommonAzureToolsPackage.Initialize()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   sp)}
>       {1E863AE9-93F6-42FD-A301-D3391F876208}
>
> ---
>
> 80004003 - E_POINTER
>       Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Just noticed that **if I authenticate to Azure through Server Explorer -> Azure beforehand I will be able to publish.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the Visual Studio Azure tooling and was later fixed.